# Delphi: TThreadList sometimes lock program

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tthread

Sometimes this function locks my program, and it's freezes until i close it.
What is wrong here ?

```
function del_from_list(id:string):boolean;
var i : integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    with global_list.LockList do
    begin
      for i:=0 to Count-1 do
      begin
        if Tthread_list(Items[i]).id = id then
        begin
          Delete(i);
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    global_list.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

the class

```
  Tthread_list = class
  public
    id   : string;
    constructor Create(const id: string);
  end;
```

I'm adding to the list like that:

```
global_list.Add(Tthread_list.Create('xxx'));
```

global list is a global variable

```
var global_list : TThreadList = nil;
```

Comment: I see no reason that this should cause a hang. Is this all the code in the app that hangs?

Comment: Most likely you have a classic deadlock situation but this code alone cannot cause it. There must be another lock somewhere.

Comment: You are deleting a class object item in a list without freeing the object first. If an exception occurs because of that, your program will lock. The answer by Remy (which you accepted) solves the lock, but not the primary error.

Comment: @LURD so can you explain how Remy's answer solves the problem. I simply must be missing something.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I assumed it solved the problem because it's the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't understand how a `list` consists of just a constructor a string field - not even a base class? Unless you only put one small snippet of this class?

Comment: @waza123 you probably should change the name of Tthread_list to something like TListItem because you might confuse people with this naming. Anyway I think downvotes should have a reason. Apart from bad naming I do not understand what people do not like in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `LockList()` outside of the `try` block instead of inside of it, eg:

```
function del_from_list(const id: string): boolean;
var
  List: TList;
  i : integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  List := global_list.LockList;
  try
    with List do
    begin
      for i :=0 to Count-1 do
      begin
        if Tthread_list(Items[i]).id = id then
        begin
          Delete(i);
          Result := True;
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    global_list.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy, I agree that the resource acquisition (lock) should be done before entering the try..finally block, but doing it the other way (OP) should only cause a problem if the resource acquisition fails and throws. Refresh my memory - can TThreadList.LockList ever throw an exception?

Comment: @Remy Do you believe that this change, which is indeed correct, will be the difference between a working app and a deadlock? If so can you explain why you believe that. If not then why did you post this as an answer? It seems like it should be a comment to me.

Comment: @dthorpe LockList today is `TMonitor.Enter(FLock); Result := FList;` so it won't throw unless there is heap corruption or a bug in `TMonitor`.

Comment: From the documentation of TList.Delete : `Note: Delete does not free any memory associated with the item.` I think the primary error here is the missing `Tthread_list(Items[i]).Free`.

Comment: @LU RD That's just a memory leak. It's not going to lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm still puzzled how Remy's answer could solve the deadlock. Yes, TMonitor could be the cause, but stepping through TMonitor source code in this example I can't find any weak points.

Comment: @dthorpe: I hadn't noticed that `TThreadList` was updated to use `TMonitor`. It used to use a `TCriticalSection` instead. That worries me, considering that `TMonitor` has known issues that have been blogged about several times.

Comment: @Remy Do you have any explanation yet as to why your answer would fix a deadlock?

Comment: As to switch to `TMonitor`, is that because critical sections are Windows only and `TThreadList` is x-plat?

Answer (score 0):

for loop counts in the wrong direction. When deleting members, you MUST count down, not up.

Comment: Not when a `Break` is used after calling `Delete()`. You only need to loop backwards if you are deleting multiple items from the list.

Comment: yeah, thats why there is a break.