# Application hangup on TIdTCPServer Contexts->LockList()

Tags: c++, deadlock, indy10

I'm developing so-called "feeder" application in C++ Builder XE2, that uses 2 built-in Indy components - TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPSever. TIdTCPClient is used to receieve data from one source, forms string message, and than with the use of TIdTCPSever this string message is sent to all clients application. For data retranslation I use the next function (idEventsServerSocket is TIdTCPSever component):

```
void TfrmMainWindow::SendDataToAllClients(String msg) {

TList *ClientsList;
try
{
ClientsList = idEventsServerSocket->Contexts->LockList();


for (int i = 0; i < ClientsList->Count; i++) {
    TIdContext *Context = (TIdContext*)ClientsList->Items[i];


    bool connected = false;
    try {
        connected = Context->Connection->Connected();
    }
    catch (Exception&e) {

        continue;
    }

    if (!connected)
        continue;
    try {
        Context->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(msg);
        Context->Connection->IOHandler->WriteBufferFlush();
    }
    catch (Exception&e) {

    }

}
}
__finally
{
idEventsServerSocket->Contexts->UnlockList();
}


}
```

I also would like to notice that this function is included in EnterCriticalSection ... LeaveCriticalSection code section, so it should be guaranteed that no new entrance to this function code will happen until the function is not exectued. For idEventsServerSocket OnException and OnListenException handlers are defined and contains empty code.

So the problem is: sometimes the line

```
ClientsList = idEventsServerSocket->Contexts->LockList();
```

is causing application hangup. No general laws when it happens, but looks like it happens most of the times when function **SendDataToAllClients** is called very frequently (say once per 10 - 50 ms). The number of clients connections varies from 30 to 50.
What I need to know, is there any way to avoid this deadlock? I there any kind of check (like TryEnterCriticalSection) ? 
Also I would like to admit that Remy's solution from [Delphi: TThreadList sometimes lock program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542260/delphi-tthreadlist-sometimes-lock-program) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

`LockList()` needs to be outside of the `try` block.

The `Contexts` list uses a critical section internally, so wrapping this code in your own critical section is redundant.

The only way `LockList()` can block is if another thread has already obtained the lock and has not released it, either because it is busy using the list, or more likely it crashed and did not release the lock.

Don't call `Connected()` or `WriteBufferFlush()` in this code.  You are not using write buffering, and calling `Connected()` from outside of the `TIdTCPServer` events will cause race conditions on the `InpuBuffer` of the connection, interferring with the server thread that manages that connection, which can lead to crashes, deadlocks, corrupted inbound data, etc.  Just call `Write()` by itself and let it throw an exception if the socket has been disconnected.

What you have shown is an unsafe way to implement TCP broadcasting with `TIdTCPServer` in general.  You should implement a per-client thread-safe outbound queue instead and let the `OnExecute` event handle the actual writing:

```
#include <IdThreadSafe.hpp>

class TMyContext : public TIdServerContext
{
public:
    TIdThreadSafeStringList *Queue;
    bool HasMsgsInQueue;

    __fastcall TMyContext(TIdTCPConnection *AConnection, TIdYarn *AYarn, TIdContextThreadList *AList = NULL)
        : TIdServerContext(AConnection, AYarn, AList)
    {
        Queue = new TIdThreadSafeStringList;
        HasMsgsInQueue = false;
    }

    __fastcall TMyContext()
    {
        delete Queue;
    }
};

__fastcall TfrmMainWindow::TfrmMainWindow(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    // set this before activating the server
    idEventsServerSocket->ContextClass = __classid(TMyContext);
}

void TfrmMainWindow::SendDataToAllClients(const String &msg)
{
    TList *ClientsList = idEventsServerSocket->Contexts->LockList();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ClientsList->Count; ++i)
        {
            TMyContext *Context = (TMyContext*) ClientsList->Items[i];
            try
            {
                TStringList *Queue = Context->Queue->Lock();
                try
                {
                    Queue->Add(msg);
                    Context->HasMsgsInQueue = true;
                }
                __finally
                {
                    Context->Queue->Unlock();
                }
            }
            catch (const Exception &)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        idEventsServerSocket->Contexts->UnlockList();
    }
}

void __fastcall TfrmMainWindow::idEventsServerSocketExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    TMyContext *ctx = (TMyContext*) AContext;
    if (ctx->HasMsgsInQueue)
    {
        TStringList *Msgs = NULL;
        try
        {
            TStringList *Queue = ctx->Queue->Lock();
            try
            {
                Msgs = new TStringList;
                Msgs->Assign(Queue);
                Queue->Clear();
                ctx->HasMsgsInQueue = false;
            }
            __finally
            {
                ctx->Queue->Unlock();
            }

            AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(Msgs);
        }
        __finally
        {
            delete Msgs;
        }
    }

    if (AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty())
    {
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->CheckForDataOnSource(100);
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->CheckForDisconnect();

        if (AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty())
            return;
    }

    // handle inbound data as needed...
}
```

Comment: thank you so  much for open my eyes for correct work with contexts, did not expect such detailed code. Will try that and feedback.

Comment: I have 10.5.8.0 Indy version, and it has no **TIdContextThreadList** defined. Can I use System::Classes::TThreadList in TMyContext constructor without changing anything else in your code?

Comment: one more question... my original code allowed immidiate retranslation (1-2 ms latency is very important in my case), and with the code provided by you I will get delay on checking the input buffer. Before in **OnExecute**   event I was just reading the data fom clients, and what now I evenualy understand is that could be the reason for the deadlock. Could the  parameter in **CheckForDataOnSource** be changed from 100 to 1 or 2 without any issues?

Comment: Yes, use `TThreadList` in earlier versions (see the declaration of the `TIdContext` constructor in `IdContext.pas`). As for latency, yes, you can reduce the timeout used. However, if your `OnExecute` handler only ever needs to read, never write, then you do not need to use the approach I showed. It is safe to read in one thread while writing in another thread without synchronizing access to the socket. I just would not advise using a send loop in the main UI thread. A blocked client will block the entire loop, which is why I moved the writes into `OnExecute` so sends could run in parallel.